# Adjust bytes stream during playback with naudio

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I am Using Naudio for a a C# audio project in Visual studio. I am looking for a simple working example of how to the adjust the read stream of a wave file before it reaches the sound card. here is a non-working example of what i want to do:

```
        public static string CurrentFile;
    public WaveOut waveout;

    public WaveFileReader wavereader {
    get { byte[] bts = //somehow Get byte buffer from reader?????
            int i = 0;
            while (i < bts.Length) {
                // do some cool stuff to the stream here
                i++; }
            return bts;//give the adjusted stream back to waveout before playback????
        }  }


    public void go()
    {
        CurrentFile = "c:/Temp/track1 - 0.wav";
        wavereader = new WaveFileReader(CurrentFile);
        waveout.Init(wavereader);
        waveout.Play();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create your own implementation of `ISampleProvider` to perform the audio manipulation. In each call to `Read` you read from the source provider (which will be the wavefilereader converted to a sample provider. And then you perform your DSP.

So the playback code will look like this (using `AudioFileReader`)

```
CurrentFile = "c:/Temp/track1 - 0.wav";
wavereader = new AudioFileReader(CurrentFile);
var myEffects = new MyEffects(waveReader)
waveout.Init(myEffects);
waveout.Play();
```

And then MyEffects looks like this:

```
class MyEffects : ISampleProvider
{
    private readonly ISampleProvider source;
    public MyEffects(ISampleProvider source)
    {
        this.source = source;
    }
    public WaveFormat { get { return source.WaveFormat; } }
    public int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int read)
    {
         var samplesRead = source.Read(buffer, offset, read);
         for(int n = 0; n < samplesRead; n++)
         {
             // do cool stuff here to change the value of 
             // the sample in buffer[offset+n]
         }
         return samplesRead;
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed edited one line to say:            public WaveFormat WaveFormat { get; set; }        and now it works great!!!